# Чтение и запись в проецируемый в память файл

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно записать текст в проецируемый в память файл. А потом прочитать. Написал код, но он не работает. Не могу разобраться, в чём проблема. fileName -- название файла, text -- текст, который нужно записать.
P.S. Прошу сильно не ругать за глупые ошибки, только начал с этим разбираться.

Запись:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile((LPCSTR)(fileName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            printf("File could not be opened.");
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return;
        }

DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
if(dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) {
      printf("GetFileSize failed");
      CloseHandle(hFile);
      return;
    }

HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, NULL, PAGE_WRITECOPY , 0, 0, NULL);
if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("File map could not be opened.");
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }

char *t;
const char *p = text;

t = ( char *) MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwFileSize);
if(t == NULL) {
  printf("MapViewOfFile failed");
  UnmapViewOfFile(t);
  CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
  CloseHandle(hFile);
  return;
}

t = new char[strlen(p)+1];
strcpy(t, p);

UnmapViewOfFile(t);
CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Чтение:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile((LPCSTR)(fileName), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("File could not be opened.");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return NULL;
    }

DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
if(dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) {
  printf("GetFileSize failed");
  CloseHandle(hFile);
  return NULL;
}

HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY , 0, 0, NULL);
if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("File map could not be opened.");
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return NULL;
    }

char *t = (char*) MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, dwFileSize);
if(t == NULL) {
  printf("MapViewOfFile failed");
  UnmapViewOfFile(t);
  CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
  CloseHandle(hFile);
  return NULL;
}

printf(t);

UnmapViewOfFile(t);
CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: Обработка ошибок отсутствует.

Comment: @VTT Обработал. Теперь говорит, что не создаётся FileMapping (выводится строка "File map could not be opened.")

Comment: Добавьте в обработчик ошибок проверку значения `GetLastError` чтобы понять, что идет не так. Еще можно заметить, что каста в `(LPCSTR)(fileName)` быть не должно.

Comment: @VTT код ошибки: 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)